# NMake inference rules with both c and cpp files

Tags: nmake

I have a project with both c and cpp files, and I've been using NMake to build. My problem is that if I have two inferences rules, one for each file type,

```
{$(dirSrc)}.c{$(dirObj)}.obj:
    cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(dirObj)\ $<

{$(dirSrc)}.cpp{$(dirObj)}.obj:
    cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(dirObj)\ $<

$(binPath): $(dirObj)\*.obj
    link /nologo /dll /out:$(binPath) $(dirObj)\*.obj
```

only the c files get compiled, presumably because the .c extension is first in the .SUFFIXES list.

I could of course simply change the extensions on the c files to cpp, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to have both rules invoked.

Answer (score 1):

*(As a reference for others in the same boat)* the problem is the `*.obj` wildcard.

That, together with the fact that if there are multiple (inference) rules for a target, only one can be reasonably applied to create/update it.

Now, the build logic from a clean state is the following *(simplified)*:

1. Need to build `$(binPath)`, let's see what it depends on...
2. There's that `*.obj`, so let't look closer...
3. Doesn't match any existing files; check if we could build it somehow...
4. Cool, an inference rule says `.obj` can be built from `.c` *(or `.cpp`, it really doesn't matter, which one is found first, see below! BTW, it's not the `.SUFFIXES` order, but the ordering of the rules in the makefile that matters here)*...
5. So, execute the compiler in the rule to create `*.obj` from its matching source, which is the non-expandable, literal `*.c`:

   → `cl /c /Fo($outdir) *.c`
6. Great, `*.obj` is now ready, go ahead to linking...
7. OK, final target, and (even though the linking may now fail for undefined externals) that's all we could do, so let's call it a day.

*Notice, how the alternative rule never even came into the picture!*

Now, for updates, assuming the broken (incomplete) target isn't there, but the object files built above are, and there're even some updates, both to some `.c` and `.cpp` files:

1. Need to build the missing `$(binPath)`, let's see what it depends on...
2. There's `*.obj`, again, which can now match existing files, so let's check them (one by one) if they need updating...
3. Then, there's the same inference rule again (whichever; there can be only one for an item, let's stick with `.c`) matching the `.obj` target in question, so check for changes in the corresponding `.c` sources...
4. They are found, so "run compiler", but this time NMAKE is smart enough to only supply the updated C sources via the `$<` macro:

   → `cl /c /Fo($outdir) some.c other.c`

   *(Note: it's even smart enough (apparently, with VS 2019 here) to go ahead and use [batch-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/batch-mode-rules?view=vs-2019) by default, even if it's not explicitly a batch rule.)*
5. OK, `*.obj` is now up-to-date again, proceed to linking...
6. Final target, same as before, end of job, celebrate! *(Let's assume now that the link has succeeded, just for the sake of the remaining examples below.)*

Again: the other rule was never needed/used for anything.

Now, curiously, you can even start deleting .obj files one by one (as long as some remain), and leave NMAKE unfazed:

```
'test.dll' is up-to-date
```

What?! Why aren't the missing ones rebuilt?

You know what? Let's delete all of them... And, just for the fun of it, replace them with a single fake one, by copying some random file there (from anywhere), renaming it to `fake.obj`.

```
'test.dll' is up-to-date
```

Jesus! This makes no sense!

OK, let's end this. Create a brand new `.c` file then. That'll sure trigger a rebuild!

```
'test.dll' is up-to-date
```

No way! :-o What the hell's going on?! Maybe adding a new `.cpp` then...

```
'test.dll' is up-to-date
```

OMG!... Such a piece of junk! Incredible, this NMAKE thing... Right?

Well... First of all, for `fake.obj`, for which there's no source with a matching name, *neither rule applies*: NMAKE can't "invent" a source for that, so it'll be never rebuilt, it's just sitting there, as a time-bomb, until the next linking round, where the linker would eventually pick it up and find out about it, ending all the fun. :)

To all the other "anomaly":

- *Any existing* .obj file will satisfy the dependency of `*.obj` (for the lib), so as long as there's at least one, NMAKE will be happy, and never even know that it's not the complete list!
- That is why nothing is ever done for any new `.c` or `.cpp` added to the project, so using a wildcard this way is shooting oneself in the foot. (Which doesn't mean there aren't any perfectly legitimate cases for wildcards in build scripts, BTW.)
- And (to recap), for rebuilding a *missing* object, NMAKE (just like gmake etc.) has to pick a winner, and ignore the rest, if there are multiple matching rules.

*(FYI, gmake even has a page specifically about this [wildcard pitfall](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Pitfall.html#Wildcard-Pitfall). And, to mitigate the risks, unlike NMAKE, it seems to refuse building the initial "complete" set of objects for a `*.o` wildcard, knowing that it'll become incomplete the minute we start adding sources — i.e. *by the very act* the wildcard was hoped to support! ;) )*

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question, the best I could think of was to compile to 2 separate directories, then point to both when running the linker.

```
{$(dirSrc)}.c{$(dirObj)\c}.obj:
    cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(dirObj)\c\ $<

{$(dirSrc)}.cpp{$(dirObj)\cpp}.obj:
    cl /nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(dirObj)\cpp\ $<

$(binPath): $(dirObj)\c\*.obj $(dirObj)\cpp\*.obj
    link /nologo /dll /out:$(binPath) $(dirObj)\c\*.obj $(dirObj)\cpp\*.obj
```